# Update a field from a Elasticsearch document

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to update a field in the documents indexed to Elasticsearch . How can i do it.

```
"redcash_sale": {
"type": "object"
}
```

update above field to below (make enable false) :-

```
sale_property_development_j/_mapping/property

{
  "properties": {
    "redcash_sale": {
      "type": "object",
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
}
```

raising error when I do mapping again to elasticsearch :-

**Error**

```
{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "mapper_exception",
"reason": "Can't update attribute for type [_doc.redcash_sale.enabled] in index mapping"
}
],
"type": "mapper_exception",
"reason": "Can't update attribute for type [_doc.redcash_sale.enabled] in index mapping"
},
"status": 500
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is to **_reindex** your data to a dest index, delete your original one and then **_reindex** again to your original one with the new mapping.

Reindex:

```
POST _reindex   
{
  "source": {
    "index": "sale_property_development_j"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_sale_property_development_j"
  }
}
```

Delete original index:

```
DELETE sale_property_development_j
```

Create requested mapping:

```
PUT sale_property_development_j
{
   "mappings":{
     "property":{
       "properties": {
         "redcash_sale": {
           "type": "object",
           "enabled": false
          }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Reindex again:

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false    
{
  "source": {
    "index": "new_sale_property_development_j"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "sale_property_development_j"
  }
}
```

Finally:

```
DELETE new_sale_property_development_j
```

It's a nice to have solution

Answer (score 1):

According to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html

Enabled cant be updated using the PUT mappings API.

You have to reindex your data then.