# Elasticsearch custom analyzer issue

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

We had to recreate registry_promotion_condition indexer which had custom analyzer called custom_value_analyzer. Because analyzer doesn't configure by indexer we have applied it through api call.

```
POST /registry_promotion_condition/_close
PUT /registry_promotion_condition/_settings
{
  "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "condition_value_analyzer" : {
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "punctuation"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer" : {
            "punctuation" : {
              "pattern" : ",",
              "type" : "pattern"
            }
          }
        }
}
POST /registry_promotion_condition/_open
```

After applying this this analyzer in dev and staging we could fetch data without problem using following api call.

```
POST /registry_promotion_condition/promotion_conditions/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "promotionDisplayStatus": {
              "value": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "conditionValue": {
              "query": 4242560,
              "analyzer": "condition_value_analyzer",
              "slop": 0,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "boost": 0.8
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "promotionId": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but in live it does't give empty response. Do you have any idea why is this. Is there any configuration to allow custom analyzer

This is my mapping in live environment

```
{
  "registry_promotion_condition" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "promotion_conditions" : {
        "properties" : {
          "conditionDataType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "conditionEntityFieldId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "conditionId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "conditionStatus" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "conditionValue" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "conditionVersion" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "createYear" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "promotionActiveFrom" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "promotionActiveUntil" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "promotionCode" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionCreatedAt" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "promotionDescription" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionDiscountAmount" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "promotionDiscountType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionDisplayName" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionDisplayStatus" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "promotionId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "promotionMaxDiscountAmount" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "promotionName" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionRuleFile" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionServiceType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionStatus" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionVersion" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "routingKey" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "in live" ? please post your mapping and an example.

Comment: we have three environment dev,stage,live live mean production

Comment: Did you reindex your data after updating your analyzer?

Comment: yep I have tried both ways. First apply analyzer to already indexed data and secondly setup analyzer and reindex in both way it's not work

Comment: Can you share your mapping?

Comment: Yes I have update the question with live environment mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your mappings from:

```
 {
  "registry_promotion_condition" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "promotion_conditions" : {
        "properties" : {
          "conditionDataType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "conditionEntityFieldId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "conditionId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "conditionStatus" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "conditionValue" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "conditionVersion" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "createYear" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "promotionActiveFrom" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "promotionActiveUntil" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "promotionCode" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionCreatedAt" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "promotionDescription" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionDiscountAmount" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "promotionDiscountType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionDisplayName" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionDisplayStatus" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "promotionId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "promotionMaxDiscountAmount" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "promotionName" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionRuleFile" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionServiceType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionStatus" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionVersion" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "routingKey" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To (added analyzer to your **conditionValue** field):

```
 {
  "registry_promotion_condition" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "promotion_conditions" : {
        "properties" : {
          "conditionDataType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "conditionEntityFieldId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "conditionId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "conditionStatus" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "conditionValue" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            },
            "analyzer":"condition_value_analyzer"
          },
          "conditionVersion" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "createYear" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "promotionActiveFrom" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "promotionActiveUntil" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "promotionCode" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionCreatedAt" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "promotionDescription" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionDiscountAmount" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "promotionDiscountType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionDisplayName" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionDisplayStatus" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "promotionId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "promotionMaxDiscountAmount" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "promotionName" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionRuleFile" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionServiceType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionStatus" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "promotionVersion" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "routingKey" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will have to delete your index in order to update your mapping and reindex again. see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644738/update-a-field-from-a-elasticsearch-document/58649509#58649509) about reindexing.