# Elastic Search : Update mapping of one field in existing index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index with the following mapping:

```
{
          "code_sourcenodedupefilecontractv4_1421_shared_5dd3788f-2d0a-4a49-b679-98bbf519013e": {
            "mappings": {
              "SourceNoDedupeFileContractV4": {
                "_meta": {
                  "version": 1421
                },
                "_routing": {
                  "required": true
                },
                "properties": {

                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .

                  "indexedTimeStamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "store": true,
                    "doc_values": false,
                    "format": "epoch_second"
                  },
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .

                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

I have to change the field `doc_value` to `true`. I have tried with the following but getting exception while trying.

```
PUT code_sourcenodedupefilecontractv4_1421_shared_5dd3788f-2d0a-4a49-b679-98bbf519013e/_mapping/SourceNoDedupeFileContractV4
{
  "properties": {
    "indexedTimeStamp": {
      "type": "date",
      "doc_values" : true
    }
  }
}
```

And the exception I am getting is while trying the command:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Mapper for [indexedTimeStamp] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [indexedTimeStamp] has different [store] values, mapper [indexedTimeStamp] has different [doc_values] values, mapper [indexedTimeStamp] has different [format] values]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Mapper for [indexedTimeStamp] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [indexedTimeStamp] has different [store] values, mapper [indexedTimeStamp] has different [doc_values] values, mapper [indexedTimeStamp] has different [format] values]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**doc_values** can not be updated.

You will have to delete your index update your mapping and reindexing your data.

See my [answer about reindexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644738/update-a-field-from-a-elasticsearch-document/58649509#58649509)

Comment: I tried without field too. Still the same error. [Updated the question too.]

Comment: Are you trying to update your mappings or create a new one? remove doc_value

Comment: No, I am trying to update the value of it. Precisely, want to set it true.

Comment: Ok now i realize what's happening here. on your update mappings query change indexedTimeStamp to SourceNoDedupeFileContractV4 and remove doc_value property since it's not supported property in fields.

Comment: I have updated the question. This time, some other error. Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, it is not allowing me to update. I tried with creating new index with the right mapping and it is working fine.