# Elasticsearch return error when querying a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some indexed data in elastic search, I am trying to use postman to get the data using the below request.

```
{
"_source": ["_id"],
"query":  {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "data",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                { "match" : {"data.id": "3456"} }
                ]
            }
        },
        "score_mode" : "avg"
    }
}
```

}

But I am getting the exception

```
[nested] nested object under path [data] is not of nested type
```

My mapping  definition is like

```
    {
  "property": {
    "mappings": {
      "property": {
        "properties": {
          "data": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "point": {
            "properties": {
              "lat": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "lon": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "popId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea why it is happening ?

Comment: Please share your mappings definition

Comment: @AssaelAzran added mapping def.

Comment: What is your elastic version? and where is **destinations** nested object in your mappings?

Comment: version is 6.7.0

Comment: Robin please add a copy-paste of the real mapping ( from GET <your_index>/_mapping . What you added seems to be a "handwritten" mapping. Plus: you certainly did not add the correct query to your question since the error mentions a "destination" path when your query to not mention it.

Comment: Via kibana cli execute **GET your index/_mapping** and post it here

Comment: updated with the result of index/_mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field `data` is an object so it should be of type **nested**.

[Nested Type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

Try these mapping configurations instead:

```
PUT property
{
  "mappings": {
    "property": {
      "properties": {
        "point": {
          "properties": {
            "lat": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "lon": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        },
        "popId": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will have to delete your index and recreate it with the new mapping configurations.

If you don't want to delete your data this might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644738/update-a-field-from-a-elasticsearch-document/58649509#58649509)

Hope it helps