# Returning all documents when query string is empty

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Say I have the following mapping:

```
{
    'properties': {
        {'title': {'type': 'text'},
        {'created': {'type': 'text'}}
    }
}
```

Sometimes the user will query by `created`, and sometimes by `title` and `created`. In both cases I want the query JSON to be as similar as possible. What's a good way to create a query that filters only by `created` when the user is not using the `title` to query?

I tried something like:

```
    {
        bool: {
            must: [
                {range: {created: {gte: '2010-01-01'}}}, 
                {query: {match_all: {}}}
            ] 
        }
    }
```

But that didn't work. What would be the best way of writing this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query didn't work cause `created` is of type `text` and not `date`, range queries on string dates will not work as expected, you should change your mappings from type `text` to `date` and reindex your data.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644738/update-a-field-from-a-elasticsearch-document/58649509#58649509) to reindex your data (with the new mappings) step by step.

Now if I understand correctly you want to use a generic query which filters `title` or/and `created` depending on the user input.

In this case, my suggestion is to use [Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

An example (version 7.4.x):

**Mappings**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "created": {  -------> change type to date instead of text
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index a few documents**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "title":"test1",
  "created": "2010-01-01"
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "title":"test2",
  "created": "2010-02-01"
}

PUT my_index/_doc/3
{
  "title":"test3",
  "created": "2010-03-01"
}
```

**Search Query (created)**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "created:>=2010-02-01",
     "fields"  : ["created"]
   }
 } 
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "test2",
          "created" : "2010-02-01"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "test3",
          "created" : "2010-03-01"
        }
      }]
```

**Search Query (title)**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "test2",
     "fields"  : ["title"]
   }
 } 
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 0.9808292,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "test2",
      "created" : "2010-02-01"
    }
  }
]
```

**Search Query (title and created)**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "(created:>=2010-02-01) AND test3"
   }
 } 
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : {
"total" : {
  "value" : 1,
  "relation" : "eq"
},
"max_score" : 1.9808292,
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "3",
    "_score" : 1.9808292,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "test3",
      "created" : "2010-03-01"
    }
  }
]
```

**fields in query string** - you can mention both fields. if you remove `fields` then the query will apply on all fields in your mappings.

Hope this helps